# Drop multiple mysql databases with a shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I am migrating one large SQL file that contains all the databases from server A to Server B. Before I can import the file I need to drop all the databases that will be recreated with the import on server B.

How do I programatically remove multiple mySQL databases with a shell script while preserving specific databases such as `information_schema`.

Comment: That's nice, but did you have a question? this site is for questions. It's not a place for you to post your "todo" lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following selects all the databases available to your mySQL user. It then filters out the databases you want to preserve using `grep`.

```
DBUSER='user'
DBPASS='password'
SQLFILE='/path/to/file/databases.sql'

echo '* Dropping ALL databases'

DBS="$(mysql -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -Bse 'show databases' |
       grep -v -e '[dD]atabase' -e mysql -e information_schema -e test)"

for db in $DBS; do
    echo "Deleting $db"
    mysql -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -Bse "drop database $db; select sleep(0.1);"
done
```

There were some partial answers but I'm hoping this will save some people some time.

TIP: You test with `$ echo $DBS` to see which Databases will be selected to be dropped after you type your first command. `DBS="$(mysql -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -Bse 'show databases' | grep -v DatabaseToFilter)"`

Comment: Using multiple `grep` commands like that is sub-optimal.  In this context, a single `grep -F` with a list of patterns/names from a file might be best, or `grep -F -v -e Database -e database …` would be better.  Granted, the number of databases is not going to be so large that there's actually a major performance issue, but it is tidier to run one command than five when one is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Johnathan, I completely agree. If you make your comment into  a full blown answer I am happy to choose it. I merely wanted to log a question I was unable to find on SO as of yet.

Comment: Because the question is on hold, I can't actually submit an answer. I've edited my proposal into the answer.  Go ahead and accept it.  I'm sorry this deprives you of the two points for accepting someone else's answer.